# Text input not populating after selection in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a modal that will give you a price of a t-shirt size based on what you have selected.
The issue I'm having is that after grabbing all the data that I need in order to get the size and price it isn't showing up in my modal.

So what needs to happen is that I would select a size and then vue would send the size to the backend and the backend will do it's thing and send it over to vue and then it should display in the textbox.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>
            <div class="modal" style="display: inline;">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">Choose T-Shirt Size</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" @click="close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <select class="form-control" v-model="content.size" @change="tshirtPrice">
                                                    <option value="S">S</option>
                                                    <option value="M">M</option>
                                                    <option value="L">L</option>
                                                    <option value="XL">XL</option>
                                                    <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
                                                    <option value="XXXL">XXXL</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        
                                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="content.price">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="close">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-3" style="float: right">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['product'],
        data() {
            return {
                content: {},
            }
        },
        computed: {

        },
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.$emit('close');
            },
            tshirtPrice(){
                axios.post(`/api/products/tshirt/prices`, {
                    'size': this.content.size
                }).then(response => {
                    this.content.size = response.data.size;
                    this.content.price = response.data.price;
                });
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.content = this.product;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I `console.log()` my response this is what I get

```
data:
    size: "S"
    price: 100
```

Comment: Your code sample has end-tag error and it works fine like DannyFeliz has said when I remove the error.You may check it in a new vue file or provide a reproducible  demo.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that will work!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is working fine. Make sure the response has the proper shape, I tested your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-byvzp5?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FModal.vue&terminal=dev) and replaced the API with mock data, and it's working fine.

Comment: I've updated my question to include what my console.log looks like

Answer (score 0):

As user can select one size at a time. You can directly show that price instead of do any comparisons/conditions.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    size: "S",
    price: 100
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Price of the size selected is Rs.{{ price }}</p>
</div>
```